Squirrel releasify fails to find files
I am trying to create an installer for my Winform app using squirrel. For some reason I can't figure out, I keep running into this error (below). The odd thing is that the files are in the package but squirrel doesn't seem to be able to find them.
Not sure if it matters but I'm using windows 10, VS 2022 and Squirrel 2.0.1.
Any help would be appreciated.
Squirrel : System.Exception: Couldn't find file for package in .: EPPlus
At line:1 char:1

+ Squirrel --releasify package.1.0.1.nupkg
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Exceptio...ge in .: EPPlus:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  
   at Squirrel.ReleasePackage.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<findAllDependentPackages>b__2(PackageDependency dependency)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Squirrel.ReleasePackage.CreateReleasePackage(String outputFile, String packagesRootDir, Func`2 releaseNotesProcessor, Action`1 contentsPostProcessHook)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.Releasify(String package, String targetDir, String packagesDir, String bootstrapperExe, String backgroundGif, String signingOpts, String 
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

baseUrl, String setupIcon, Boolean generateMsi, Boolean packageAs64Bit, String frameworkVersion, Boolean generateDeltas)
at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String\[\] args)
at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String\[\] args)
at Squirrel.Update.Program.Main(String\[\] args)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling squirrel, restarting VS, deleting and recreating the package but nothing seems to work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
